# Number of ways to write $n$ as sum of odd or even number of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, fibonacci-numbers

In our discrete mathematics exercises I came of with the question:

> Prove that the coefficients of
>   $\prod_{n\geq2}{(1-x^{F_n})}=1-x-x^2+x^4+x^7+\dots$ can only be $-1,1$
>   or $0$, where $F_n$ denotes the n'th fibonacci number.

If we want to find the coefficient of $x^n$, we should choose some distinct terms from the products so that $n$ is written as sum of some fibonacci numbers , and because each term is in the form of $(1-x^{F_n})$, if we choose an odd number of them we will have  $-1$ and if we choose an even number of them we will have  $+1$.
 So the question is the same as:

> Prove that the number of ways to write a natural number as sum of odd
>   number of fibonacci numbers differs at most $1$ number from number of ways of writing it
>   as sum of even number of fibonacci numbers

(Note that the noted fibonacci numbers start from $F_2$)
My approach using induction is as follows:
Assume the proposition is true for all values of $n<k$, we shall prove it for $n=k$.
First note that for every number $k$ there exists $m$ so that $F_m\leq k < F_{m+1}$. We take $A=k-F_m$. Obviously $A<k$ so by induction hypothesis the proposition is true for $A$.There are two different possibilities for $A$:
**1)** $A<F_{m-2}$
In this case we have $k=F_m+A=F_{m-1}+F_{m-2}+A$. Note that because $A<F_{m-2}$, we have a one to one correspondence between the odd ways and the even ways and so the difference will stay $+1,0,-1$ depending on $A$
**2)** $A\geq F_{m-2}$
I'm actually stuck here and I cant find a similar proof for this case. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: You wrote $(1-x)^{F_n}$ once and $(1-x^{F_n})$ once -- which one do you mean?

Comment: The second one! Thanks for noting, i edited the question.

Comment: I don't quite understand your argument in case 1). The issue is that not every representation of $k$ is obtained from one of your $A$. E.g. when $k=14$, $A=1$ has only one such representation. But $14=13+1=8+5+1=8+3+2+1$.

Answer (score 1):

The following papers provide a proof of OPs claim:

- Federico Ardila presents in *[The Coefficients of a Fibonacci Power Series](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0409418v1.pdf)* a clever subdivision of the interval
  $$[F_n,F_{n+1})$$
  into three parts and proves that consecutive intervals have *essentially* the same shape. Then a rather simple induction proof can be used to finalize the claim.
- Neville Robbins *[Fibonacci Partitions](http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/FQ/Scanned/34-4/robbins.pdf)* provided a different proof some years earlier.

It could be interesting to note, that these proofs do not refer to the *[Zeckendorf representation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeckendorf%27s_theorem)* of natural numbers as unique sum of different, non-consecutive Fibonacci numbers.

The coefficients of this product
$$\prod_{n\geq 2}\left(1-x^{F_n}\right)$$
can be found in OEIS as *[A093996](https://oeis.org/A093996)*.

Comment: The Yufei Zhao reference in the OEIS entry is also worth a look. (+1)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: You're right! Thanks!